# Not install ngx-mqtt in angular 6?

Tags: angular6

Whenever I want to install ngx-mqtt in my angular application it not installed. There was an error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEhla.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in node project and tried to install in node project. Make sure you are in `angular` project.

I have create a new angular project and tried to install it. And it installed perfectly.

[image: MQTT]

Comment: Now are you able to install module ?

Comment: Yeah. I'm solved this problem by using npm install ngx-mqtt@next

Comment: Great, If my answer helps you then accept or upvote it.